# MongoLab DB is not responding when using with localhost

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose, mlab

I have an Heroku web applicaiton based on MongoLab MongoDB.
Accessing the site via heroku production site works and I see the site is alive.

My development environment is configured to work with the production DB.
When I try to connect I get on:

```
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
...
});
```

And err.message = "connect ETIMEDOUT 54.159.67.179:61188"

How should I continue?

Comment: Let me know if there is a missing information here to add

Comment: Just to close the loop - its just started to work again, my guess there was a problem with 3rd party servers (Heroku/MongoLab)

Answer (score 0):

If you click through the resources section of the heroku dashboard and then open your mlab resource it should take you to the mlab home.

The first bit of information should show you how to connect to your database either though the mongo shell or using the standard URI. If you have mongo installed locally can you connect to the remote database this way? If not then it points to network issues. Are you accessing this from behind a corporate proxy? Mongo by default uses port 27017 which isn't open on most corporate proxies. If this is the case then I would speak to your network administrator. I know that at my company we aren't allowed to use this port, but then we don't use cloud infrastructure (yet). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Matthew for trying to help, I connected successfully with MongoChef, So its seems I dont have network issues

Comment: Interesting, so you can connect locally from MongoChef but not through node. Are you specifying the database in the URI in node?

Comment: Yes I've specified the URI in node.
I've just tried to create the development environment on another computer and now mongoose has connected successfully - I guess it means something is blocking the application to reach mongoLab on my specific computer.
Need to further investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Solution for me ended up that the environment variable (stored in a .env file in my app) had an old "configvar" (Heroku terminology) and:

1. go to the desired app `Settings` tab in Heroku
2. click the `Reveal ConfigVars` button
3. copy the `MONGODB_URI` value
4. paste the URI into the .env file (or wherever you store)

That was it, back in business.